# change href text value

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">mark picked</a>
```

I want to change href text(mark picked) to mark delivered.
how can  I do this thing?

Comment: try now with my new answer!!

Answer (score 1):

i tried with onclick of that anchor tag else if you want do this somehwhere. try this

> $("#a_tbnotesverbergen").text("mark delivered");

```js
$('#a_tbnotesverbergen').click(function(){
$("#a_tbnotesverbergen").text("mark delivered");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">mark picked</a>
```

Comment: but i need some more help

Comment: say, how can i help

Comment: I emailed a file to you  please me  out this

Comment: Ganesh go  through new answer which is post by me

Comment: try my new answer, just posted, may be this will help u

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a_tbnotesverbergen").click(function(){
        $(this).text('tesxt Changed!!!!');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">mark picked</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#a_tbnotesverbergen").text("mark delivered");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".waves-effect3").click(function() {
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("id");
 var oid = $(this).attr("name");

    });
        alert(oid);
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'updategoingorder.php',
            data: {'id': addressValue, 'name': oid},
            success: function(){
    
     alert("Status Updated!!!");
   }
        });
  
});
```

```html
<td><a href="#" class="waves-effect3" id="ajax"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span>Mark Picked</span></a><br>';
```

i want to change mark picked to mark delivered in href text on click a link and post this value to updategoingorder.php page

Answer (score 0):

Already those values are sent to updategoingorder.php,
you can access them by using this in updategoingorder.php file

```
$addressValue= $_POST['id']; 
$name= $_POST['name']; 
echo $addressValue + $name;
```

```js
$(".waves-effect3").click(function() {
    var addressValue = $(".waves-effect3 span").attr("id");
 $(".waves-effect3 span").text("mark delivered");
var oid = $(".waves-effect3 span").text();
  
        alert(oid);
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'updategoingorder.php',
            data: {'id': addressValue, 'name': oid},
            success: function(){
    
     alert("Status Updated!!!");
   }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><a href="#" class="waves-effect3" id="ajax"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span>Mark Picked</span></a><br>
```

Comment: i want to send oid and addressvalue to updategoingorder.php page how can i send these values?

Comment: code updated, check once, alreday those values are sent to another php file

Comment: <td><a href="#" name="'. $oid .'" class="waves-effect3" id="'. $data[$i]['name'] .'"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span>Mark Picked</span></a><br> this is a link which and values i want to pass to updategoingoreder.php

Comment: i want to post $oid and $data[$i]['name']  values to updategoingorder.php

Comment: this code didn't post $oid and $data[$i]['name'] values to updategoingorder.php

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

$("#a_tbnotesverbergen").attr("href", "mark delivered");

Comment: This code will not change text in `a` tag it will change `href`, please read question properly and answer

Comment: Sorry but question was change href value not  a tag value. so ... Thanks

Comment: Please check all answer and Q description and code, think so you will understand it